# What does "beyond" mean?

Tags: meaning, definition, word-meaning

Sometimes it's really hard for me to understand what does a word of "beyond" mean.
In the movie Arrival the character of Amy Addams says:

> I'm not so sure I believe in beginnings and endings. There are days
>   that define your story beyond your life. Like the day they arrived.

The only guess I have is the second sentence means something like: There are days that affect your story even though you life hasn't began yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Dictionary

> be·yond preposition & adverb
>
> 1. at or to the further side of. "he pointed to a spot beyond the trees" synonyms:    on the far side of, on the other side of, further
>      away than, behind, past, after, over More
> 2. happening or continuing after (a specified time or event). "we can manage another two years, but beyond that the system is not viable"
>
> synonyms: on the far side of, on the other side of, further away than,
>   behind, past, after, over "beyond the trees" noun
>
> 1. the unknown after death. "messages from the beyond"

I'd say "days that define your story beyond your life", means, outside of your life as if it could be viewed in its entirety from outside and examined. This examination would help you to understand and define your life.